# Shipping method "Local pickup" makes other shipping alternatives dissapear in checkout

Tags: woocommerce

For some reason, when "Local pickup" option is active in a shipping zone does other shipping options disappear.
[image: Local pickup enabled]

[image: Shipping alternatives]

But when I disable "Local pickup" the other options show up.
[image: Local pickup disabled]
[image]

I don't know if this affect it but for example (this product) has this shipping class active
[image: Shipping class]

I have the following shipping zones.
[image]

I don't know where to start or what the problem can be. All help is appreciated

Comment: and what is the setup of your zones ?

Comment: @MartinMirchev I have added a print screen of the shipping zones 

Comment: I guess Frakt is fixed price? But why u have 2 times free delivery ? What u have set for free delivery ? City , Region or Country ? And when u test what u fill for delivery location ?